# Building chain link node for Alarm clock

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

After following the Guide on the [chain-link doc for building a node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5O1l.png) I got stuck,

Going through this https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/migration-v1-v2/ I notice that lots have changed How do I create a new JOBID with V2 that will suit the Alarm clock oracle contract as seen here will I just copy and paste it here just like the V1? [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5O1l.png)

```html
type                = "directrequest"
schemaVersion       = 1
name                = "Get > Bytes32"
contractAddress     = "0x19f7f3bF88CB208B0C422CC2b8E2bd23ee461DD1"
externalJobID       = "0EEC7E1D-D0D2-476C-A1A8-72DFB6633F47" # OPTIONAL - if left unspecified, a random value will be automatically generated
observationSource   = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=http method=get url="$(decode_cbor.url)"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="$(decode_cbor.path)"]
    encode_data  [type=ethabiencode abi="(uint256 value)" data=<{ "value": $(parse) }>]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data=<{
                      "requestId": $(decode_log.requestId),
                      "payment": $(decode_log.payment),
                      "callbackAddress": $(decode_log.callbackAddr),
                      "callbackFunctionId": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId),
                      "expiration": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration),
                      "data": $(encode_data)
                  }>]
    submit       [type=ethtx to="$(jobSpec.contractAddress)" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit
"""
```

Your help will go a long way.

Comment: Why not use the keepers here instead? https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/

Comment: Thanks @PatrickCollins for taking your time to look at this, truly just want to have idea on how the alarm clock works also keeper is not on the choice network(BSC) so that is one of the reason i decided to run a test with alarm clock.

Comment: Also when i used the alarm clock jobID i got an error "Sleep Adapter is not implemented yet", i wish i can get a way out with this.
thanks for checking in.

Comment: You need an environment variable to run the sleep adapter: https://docs.chain.link/docs/core-adapters/#sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.env` set `ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL_ADAPTERS=true` and restart your node.